# Why my new site of Wordpress is keeping loading when i install a specific theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, hosting

I try to install many times a specific premium theme from themeforest in wordpress and the site keep loading for many hours.I try to install the same thing to another site and doing the same stuck in loading for hours.

I contact to the developer of the theme and he said to contact with the technicians of my host and to edit the htaccess file puting these values in the 1st line of the file: php_value post_max_size 2048M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2048M
php_value memory_limit 2048M
php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value max_input_time 600
I did it and i continue to have the same problem, but the technician of my host installed this theme successfully. I don't know why i cannot install the specific theme from my computer, i tried from another connection and another laptop and i have the same error the page keep loading without do anything else.
If i try to install an other theme, it install it successfully.
I don't have any vpn, or plugin to my browser, and i uploaded the theme that i try to install to the same directory of htaccess but didn't help.
Please can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Contact your host provider for assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘the same directory of htaccess’?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.